# Can't get an entity

Tags: angular, angular6

I have thoses two classes:

Student *---1 adresse

```
export class Student
{
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    adresse: Adresse;
}

export class Adresse
{
    id: number;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    town: string;
    city: string;
}
```

I go to select a student from the **list-student.component.ts**

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="!loader">
        <tr *ngFor="let student of userbs | async" style="width: 1500px;">
          <td>{{student.id}}</td>
          <td>{{student.name}}</td>
          <td><span class="button is-small btn-warning" (click)='editUser(student)'>Update</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

and the function `editUser` was defined inside **modify-student.component.ts** like that:

```
 editUser(student: Student): void
    {
        console.log("--------------Student's adress: " + -->  It gives the error.
        console.log("--------------Student's name: " + student.name);  -->  It gives the expected name for Example AJT_82 or Adrita.

        this.router.navigate(['modify-student']);
    };
```

I got this error when trying to recuperate the email of student on the `console.log`.

> ERROR TypeError: "student.adresse is undefined"

[This is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScQvy.png)

Thanks to Sir @AJT_82 and Mrs @Adrita, I know the cause of the problem.
This error appears due to consuming rest service from backend (Spring Boot). I add the annotation

```
@JsonIgnore 
private Adresse adresse;
```

That's why on postman, I can't show the adress object inside the student.
That's why I got undefined for adresse caused by `@JsonIgnore`. 
But that will cause another exception on spring boot due to eliminating `@JsonIgnore` which is

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6].

Have you please any idea about solving that ?.
Big thanks.

Comment: well does `student` and `student.addresse` and `student.addresse.email` have values? looks that `student` is `undefined` to me based on what you are showing.

Comment: I would suggest an interface, if you have no class specific methods. But anyway... here's the JS Class documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Hello Sir @AJT_82. Thanks a lot for your reply. I have the list of student on the list-students interface, after click on Update, I have to recuperate the information of the selected student. I can recuperate the name, but I got the error that I attached above (student.adresse is undefined), Could you please take a look, I made some changes on my question.

Comment: well the error image is totally different from what you have written in your question...

Comment: in` editUser()` please `console.log("--------------Student's : " + student.); and show the result

Comment: You're right. I attached it with error. But the error was ERROR TypeError: "student.adresse is undefined"

Comment: so what does `console.log(student)` produce? Apparently `addresse` is `undefined` like the error suggests.

Comment: It produces  [object Object]

Comment: are you **sure** that you are consoling `console.log(student)`?? That shouldn't happen. Sounds to me you are using `+ student` somewhere in your console.log

Comment: Yes, I put this console on the method **editUser(student: Student)** and console.log("Student's name: " + student.name);  -->  It gives the expected name for Example **Adrita**.

Comment: can your please `console.log(student)`, that **EXACT SAME LINE** line and show the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please ensure the unidirectional of the mapping of Student and Adresse.
HTH.